# Update every row in a table with PHP in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
  Table
*------------------------------------------------*
|    id    |    title   |    filename            |
*------------------------------------------------*
```

Lets say this is the structure of the table. I want to update every single row of this table.

Lets say i want to replace every space in Filename with a underscore.

```
$new_filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Filename = '$new_filename'");
```

This does not work. Each row has different Filename.

Comment: so each row has a different filename and in each row you want to replace spaces with underscores in each of those filenames?

Comment: What happens if you *try* it?

Comment: Brian, because the Filename is not set, the Filename of all rows in the table are empty after the command

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would simply do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Filename = REPLACE(Filename, ' ', '_')");
```

This way you only execute one command and depending on your table size, this should be pretty quick

*edited

Comment: Thank you! What if i wanted to search for something and replace any rows that had a Filename that matches the search?

Comment: You just add a where clause eg: `WHERE filename` = 'Some file'`. read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html and also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Its a great way, but I would be more interested in a general answer. Letsay, what if the change was not so simple. For example the database entry has a short HTML snippet containing embed code of a video and few other things. 
I want to change that embed code to HTML5 complaint and change those nubmers to f(original nos). This I guess would require querying through php and then updating the row in it.

Answer (score 3):

First answer is way better :)

So your filename is in every row the same? otherwise this code would replace all the filenames with one name. You will need a for loop get the data from the table and update it.

Like this:

```
    $query = "SELECT id, filename FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    if($result){
        $num = mysql_numrows($result);
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num) {
            $new_filename = str_replace("_", " ", mysql_result($result,$i,"filename"));
            $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET filename = '$new_filename' WHERE id='$id'");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This helped me more than the chosen answer because the update I needed would have been very tough to do in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

That will work, provided you have connected to the database using mysql_connect() first.

If you are just doing this as a one-off your solution is fine - but if you are allowing users to do this via a form of some kind then you have a security flaw called SQL Injection. If the variable $filename is submitted by a user, then they could end the query and start a new one. You should never place unsanitised data into a MySQL query.

To get round this put $filename through mysql_real_escape_string or even better use prepared statements provided by MySQLi or PDO.